# Selenium : No Response from Server

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2015, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I am getting following error in UI BDDs. It is very flaky.

Error :
-> error: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:58302/session/923d8e6bb53fc838c57552f48fddd206/element timed out after 60 seconds.

**I am using following versions of selenium :**

package id="Selenium.Support" version="2.53.0" targetFramework="net451"

package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="2.53.0" targetFramework="net451"

package id="SpecFlow" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="net4"

**Chrome driver version :**

package id="Chromium.ChromeDriver" version="2.19" targetFramework="net4"

**Google Chrome Portable Version :**

package id="googlechrome-portable" version="49.0.2623.112" targetFramework="net4"

I am running these UI BDD's on portable google chrome.

Could you please let me know how to fix it ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can try http://www.seleniumwiki.com/webdriver/resolving-chromedriver-no-response-from-server-for-url/

It's help for me!